# How to add a right-click menu in Electron that has "Inspect Element" option like Chrome?

Tags: electron

I'm building an Electron application and I would like to inspect specific UI elements. I have the Chrome dev tools open for development, but what I want is to be able to right-click a UI element and choose "Inspect Element" like I can in Google Chrome. Currently, right-clicking doesn't do anything in my boilerplate Electron app. How can I enable this?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Electron has a built-in function called [win.inspectElement(x, y)](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#wininspectelementx-y).

Including this function as an option in a right-click context menu is possible by creating an Electron `Menu` with a `MenuItem`. Call the following in the client (aka *renderer* process) Javascript:

```js
// Importing this adds a right-click menu with 'Inspect Element' option
const remote = require('remote')
const Menu = remote.require('menu')
const MenuItem = remote.require('menu-item')

let rightClickPosition = null

const menu = new Menu()
const menuItem = new MenuItem({
  label: 'Inspect Element',
  click: () => {
    remote.getCurrentWindow().inspectElement(rightClickPosition.x, rightClickPosition.y)
  }
})
menu.append(menuItem)

window.addEventListener('contextmenu', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  rightClickPosition = {x: e.x, y: e.y}
  menu.popup(remote.getCurrentWindow())
}, false)
```

Comment: In case someone could find it useful, I created a repo on github based on your answer. You can find it here: [debug-menu](https://github.com/parro-it/debug-menu)

Comment: In the latest version of electron (0.36.11) I had to call `remote.getCurrentWindow()` inside the event handler for this to work, rather than caching in the currentWindow constant.

Comment: If you are using typings the `inspectElement` does not exist on `BrowserWindow`. You could do `remote.getCurrentWindow().webContents.inspectElement` instead.

Comment: The import statements have changed; also there is now an [example in the docs](http://electron.atom.io/docs/api/menu/#render-process)

Answer (score 18):

Try [electron-context-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-context-menu). It adds `inspect element`, `copy` and `paste`.

Comment: That works great for Forge as well.!
I'd like to point out though that this feature does not belong to a native app, so it should somehow be dropped for production

Comment: The context menu made by this package cannot be changed depending on where you click.