# NightmareJS rightclick/contextmenu action

Tags: electron, nightmare

I've been struggling for the past day to make nightmarejs force context menu opening. I've tried creating a custom action using the `sendInputEvent('contextmenu',....)` function of Electron's `webContents` browser object but to no avail. I'm starting to think this is not possible at the moment. Any suggestions?

Here is my custom Nightmare action:

```
Nightmare.action("rightClick", function(name, options, parent, win, renderer, done) {
  parent.respondTo("rightClick", function(x, y, done) {
    win.webContents.sendInputEvent({
      type: "contextmenu",
      x: x, y: y,
      clickCount: 1
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      done();
    }, 25);
  });
  done();
}, function(x, y, done) {
  this.child.call("rightClick", x, y, done);
});
```

I also tried to simulate mousedown-mouseup functionality to no avail

```
Nightmare.action("rightClick", function(name, options, parent, win, renderer, done) {
  parent.respondTo("rightClick", function(x, y, done) {
    win.webContents.sendInputEvent({
      type: "mousedown",
      x: x, y: y,
      modifiers: ["rightButtonDown", "right"],
      clickCount: 1
    });
    win.webContents.sendInputEvent({
      type: "mouseup",
      x: x, y: y,
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
      done();
    }, 25);
  });
  done();
}, function(x, y, done) {
  this.child.call("rightClick", x, y, done);
});
```

Comment: Electron does not have context menu of its own. Check this answer [Adding electron context-menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32636750/how-to-add-a-right-click-menu-in-electron-that-has-inspect-element-option-like)

Comment: the application I'm testing has a context menu of its own which triggers on "right click" and my goal is for Nightmare to trigger it but for some reason it can't...

Comment: Can you share a sample of context menu created? I can try opening it up :)

Comment: There is no exposed API method that opens the context menu it only opens using right-click. The goal is obviously to **not** have to create special methods just for our tests otherwise frameworks become pointless.

Comment: Nightmare is an open extensible framework. It does not have right-click as of now but we can add functionality which can be added to it (as plugin or core action). This might become part of framework itself later if it is generic enough.

Comment: The problem is that it is impossible to create an action / plugin for it. At least not the way actions were meant to be made